# Rearranging two vectors correlated in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am analyzing the efficiency of multiple circuits using matlab. The output is a maximum working distance and the power of the circuit analyzed. The output of this vectors is the following:

```matlab
>> display(distance)

distance =

     8    21    21     4     3     8     3     8     2     6    10     7     6     8    12    11     6     8

>>display(power)

power =

  Columns 1 through 13

    3.2047    3.5666    3.7578    1.8184    3.0810    3.7973    2.8699    3.3953    2.5971    3.1933    3.8191    3.7992    3.4802

  Columns 14 through 18

    4.1104    4.0836    3.2191    3.9155    0.2394
```

As you can see I have the circuit 1 that has a power of 3.2047 and a maximum distance of 8m. I have the circuit 6 that has the same maximum distance with a 3.7973 power. I want to rearrange the `distance` vector in order to it to be crescent (starting with 2 and ending with 21 for instance) and be able to rearrange the `power` accordingly. Below you have the `display` that I would like to see doing this to clarify this question.

```matlab
>> display(distanceReorganized)

distanceReorganized =

     2    3    3     4     6     6     6     7     8     8    8     8     8     10    11     12     21    21

>>display(powerReorganized)

powerReorganized =

  Columns 1 through 13

    2.5971    2.8699    3.0810    1.8184    3.1933    3.4802    3.9155    3.7992    0.2394    3.2047    3.3953    3.7973    4.1104

  Columns 14 through 18

    3.8191    3.2191    4.0836    3.5666    3.7578
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [second output argument](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) from `sort`.

```
[~,I] = sort(distance, 'ascend');
distanceReorganized = distance(I);
powerReorganized = power(I);
```

**Edit:** Based on your comment, `sortrows` should do what you are looking for:

```
circuitData = table(distance', power', 'VariableNames', {'Distance', 'Power'});
sortrows(circuitData,{'Distance','Power'})
```

You can then reassign the columns of the table to new vector variables should you wish to.

Here is the documentation for [sortrows](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.sortrows.html).

Comment: This works correctly to sort the distance, however I want to also sort the power in an ascend format. Using this my `distanceReorganized(9:13)` is equal to 8 and my `powerReorganized(9:13) = 3.2047    3.7973    3.3953    4.1104    0.2394`. There is a way that I can rearrange the powerReorganized(9:13)` in an ascend format?